# Configure Azure SFTP Gateway with multiple storage accounts

Tags: azure, sftp

I have implemented Azure SFTP Gateway.

I looked everywhere and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

During the configuration, you set a Storage account where the use can deploy its file. And you can set different blobs for different users if required, but I couldn't find anywhere if its possible or not to have multiple storage accounts.

In sftp gateway webpage, under setting, I have the option to set only one storage account. Is this a limitation of the service?

Do I need a SFTP Gateway VM for each storage account?

Thank you very much for your help and any clarification.

Comment: This one https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/thorntechnologiesllc.sftpgateway?tab=overview?

Comment: Yes I have that one. But in the configuration I can set only one storage account. How about if I want the sftp to manage different storage accounts?

Comment: this is a third-party product, not created or supported by Microsoft. I'd suggest to reach out over the support email they've provided.

Answer (score 0):

For SFTP Gateway version 2 on Azure, only one Blob Storage Account can be configured per VM. This is because of a product limitation -- the Blob Storage Account connection settings are global to the VM. You can point SFTP users to different containers within the same Blob Storage Account. But if you wanted to point to separate Storage Accounts, that would require a separate VM.

For SFTP Gateway version 3 on Azure, you can configure "Cloud Connections". These let you point SFTP users to different Blob Storage Accounts, so you only need to use one VM.

As abatishchev mentioned, contacting the product owner's support email is a good approach.